# Getting text of checked checkbox in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I am having some difficulties when trying to get the text of checkbox using javascript. Here is the code for my html:

```
content += "<tr><td><input id='type_select1' class=\"pss\"  type=\"checkbox\" onclick='queryPSS()' >Commercial and Residential</td><td><input id='type_select2' class=\"pss\"  type=\"checkbox\" onclick='queryPSS()' >Commercial</td></tr>";
content += "<tr><td><input id='type_select3' class=\"pss\"  type=\"checkbox\" onclick='queryPSS()'>Heavy Vehicle Park</td><td><input id='type_select4' class=\"pss\"  type=\"checkbox\" onclick='queryPSS()'>Hospital</td></tr>";
content += "<tr><td><input id='type_select5' class=\"pss\"  type=\"checkbox\" onclick='queryPSS()'>Hotel</td><td><input id='type_select6' class=\"pss\"  type=\"checkbox\" onclick='queryPSS()'>Industrial</td></tr>";
content += "<tr><td><input id='type_select7' class=\"pss\"  type=\"checkbox\" onclick='queryPSS()'>Industrial-White</td><td><input id='type_select8' class=\"pss\"  type=\"checkbox\" onclick='queryPSS()'>Office</td></tr>";
content += "<tr><td><input id='type_select9' class=\"pss\"  type=\"checkbox\" onclick='queryPSS()'>Recreation</td><td><input id='type_select10' class=\"pss\"  type=\"checkbox\" onclick='queryPSS()'>Residential (Landed)</td></tr>";
content += "<tr><td><input id='type_select11' class=\"pss\"  type=\"checkbox\" onclick='queryPSS()'>Residential (Non-Landed)</td><td><input id='type_select12' class=\"pss\"  type=\"checkbox\" onclick='queryPSS()'>Residential</td></tr>";
content += "<tr><td><input id='type_select13' class=\"pss\"  type=\"checkbox\" onclick='queryPSS()'>White Site</td></tr>";
```

And here is how I get the text of checked checkbox:

```
var type_select = document.getElementById('type_select');
if(type_select.checked == true)
{
   var type_filter = type_select.text;
   alert(type_filter);
}
```

However, When I check a check box, the pop up message display "`undefined`". I wonder what went wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: i hope you realise that multiple form elements cannot have the same id

Comment: Is there any other way to fix this? Because what I am trying to do is get the text of checked checkbox and perform other functions

Comment: you can give them diff ids.for eg. type_select1,type_select2,type_select3..point to note is that they must be unique.thats it

Comment: But after I set them to different ID, how I store the checked checkbox as type_filter? Would you mind to provide me some examples

Comment: @user13500 I changed the ID already but how do I proceed from there?

Comment: `<input id="type_select" class="pss" type="checkbox" onclick="queryPSS()"/>` no use `/\/` and `<input />` close `/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so i finally get what you are trying to do. to begin with lets consider one sample from your content string.

```
<td><input class=\"pss\"  type=\"checkbox\" onclick='queryPSS()' value = "myValue">Commercial and Residential</td>
```

We still have different ids. But on click you fire the customFunction(can even be queryPSS) like this. Make sure you also add the value attribute and set it to the required value.

```
onclick = customFunction(this)
```

Somewhere down, you define the function like this,

```
function customFucntion(idValue){
   var elem = idValue.value;
}
```

thats it. That should work.

Comment: Don't bother with the `id`s - in most of the cases where people spend a lot of time figuring out that you can't give multiple elements the same id, then trying to figure out how to give them all unique ids, you don't need them.  Just call `customFunction(this)` and in the function, `idValue.value`

Comment: @Dennis thats a good point. I will keep that in mind.thanks :)

Comment: So for my case, inside the checkbox tag, I should put this: onclick = queryPSS(this) ?

Comment: yes. but make sure you include the function too. the elem variable would contain the value that you need.

Comment: thats great. am glad i could help.

Comment: @Scrooj Hey there, I realized there is some problem. When multiple checkbox checked, the elem would not be append. Why is it so?

Comment: because its just a variable.to hold all of the values use an array. and something like elem.push(idValue.value);make sure to define elem as an array outside of the function.